# Close React Native Expo Camera

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-camera

Random question, I've created a camera app and on iOS, the green dot (signifying that the camera is in use) stays on even when the camera screen is not in use. Do I need to "close" the camera when it's not in use or anything like that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you unmount your camera screen, the camera will be in use.

When you unfocus the camera screen, use the pausePreview() method: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#pausepreview

When you focus on the screen, use the resumePreview() method instead: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#resumepreview